# Bad location Google Maps Xamarin Forms (Middle of the ocean)

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.forms.Maps and ExtendedMap, I did make a custom control, here I can get the location when the user tap on map but by default the map position is in the middle of the occean, something like this 0.0756931, 0.0786793. I was seaching and trying for a while but I did not find the solution.
I did see that the map is loading the region.LatitudeDegrees and region.LongitudeDegrees but I really don't why is this happen.

Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.482510

Xamarin.Forms.Maps 3.0.0.482510

Xamarin.Plugin.ExternalMaps 4.0.1

MapGoogleView.xaml

```
<local:ExtendedMap 
                WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
                x:Name="MyMap"  Tap="OnTap"
                IsShowingUser="true"
                MapType="Street"/>
```

MapGoogleView.xaml.cs

```
public MapGoogleView(double lat, double lon)
        {

                InitializeComponent();
                NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

                var map = new ExtendedMap(
                    MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                        new Position(lat, lon), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
                {
                    IsShowingUser = true,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    WidthRequest = 900,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    MapType = MapType.Street
                };
 var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
                stack.Children.Add(map);
                Content = stack;

var position = new Position(lat, lon); // Latitude, Longitude
                var pin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Generic,
                    Position = position,
                    Label = "Ubicación",
                    Address = "Latitud: " + lat.ToString() + ", Longitud: " + lon.ToString(),
                };
                MyMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                map.MoveToRegion(
                MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                new Position(lat, lon), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
}
```

ExtendedMap.cs

```
public class ExtendedMap : Map
    {
        public event EventHandler<TapEventArgs> Tap;

        public ExtendedMap()
        {

        }

        public ExtendedMap(MapSpan region) : base(region)
        {

        }

        public void OnTap(Position coordinate)
        {
            OnTap(new TapEventArgs { Position = coordinate });
        }

public async void OnTap(Position coordinate)
        {
            try
            {

                    OnTap(new TapEventArgs { Position = coordinate });
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                    "Error",
                    error.Message,
                    "Aceptar");

                return;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnTap(TapEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = Tap;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class TapEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Position Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Droid
ExtendedMapRenderer.cs

```
public class ExtendedMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap _map;



        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            _map = googleMap;
            if (_map != null)
                //_map.GestureRecognizer.Add(new);
                _map.MapClick += googleMap_MapClick;
        }

        public ExtendedMapRenderer()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e) //cambiar a xamarin.forms.view
        {
            if (_map != null)
                _map.MapClick -= googleMap_MapClick;
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }

        private void googleMap_MapClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs e)
        {

            ((ExtendedMap)Element).OnTap(new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude));
        }


    }
```

Comment: are you using a real device or an emulator?

Comment: Real device @Jason

Comment: Have you enabled the location permission in the android manifest or on the phone?

Comment: If not let me know here and ill explain it in an answer/

Comment: Yes, I did. @JamesMallon. I did really implement another example without using a custom renderer and it's runs ok, show the position fine but in that example I can't get the location when I tap on map.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling to obtain the Latitude and Longitude coordinates using the plugins described above, you could obtain your devices lon/lat by doing the following:

Download and install into your application the [Geolocator Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin). Made by the man the myth the legend [James Montemagno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3085228/jamesmontemagno).

Following that, you can follow [this](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/) guide to obtain your devices longitude and latitude coordinates.

On doing that you can assign your global lat and lon variables to the values retrieved using that plugin. I don't know if you did this prior to instantiating your maps or have used a different method but this is how I get my devices Lat & Lon.

As a fallback if a device has location disabled or does not have the ability to retrieve its GPS data I always set my default lat & lon to the capital city of the devices country region.

```
RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

then if UK set the lat & lon to london city center for example.

Comment: I'm using Geolocator Plugin to get my location and work's well.

Comment: I'm following this example https://julianocustodio.com/2018/02/09/adicione-pontos-no-maps/ and I did test in a new project and works fine, but when I try to test in my project doesn't work, I can't install GooglePlayServices.Maps

Comment: @EleazarSaavedra  this is most likely due to conflicts between packages, what is the error you receive in the console when you try and download play services, open a chat with me if you like, I’ll be back online 8am gmt

Comment: this "a version conflict for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.". I'm follow this to solve the problem https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111931/cannot-update-googleplayservices-60-1142-0 but now I got a lot of errors because I cleaned the cache nugets

Comment: Take note of all nugget packages that you know you need/require. Remove all nugget packages from solution, re install 1 by 1 nuget packages, read each ones description and if it says should not be installed on its own only as a dependency, don’t install it.